# ASP.NET web project using VB and .NET 5 (core)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019, asp.net5

Trying to build a SignalR server using .NET5 (core) and VB for language. When I open VS 2019 with latest v16.3 there is no project template available for this type of project. Only C# is available. I have seen others in videos that have built projects like this with VB but haven't been able to figure out how. I have the Enterprise version of VS. Could it be that only this version lacks this template? Is there a place to download this template or download an empty project of this type that I can use?

Comment: Did you find any solution

Comment: No I haven't found one.

Comment: check this link
https://dotnetthoughts.net/building-aspnet-core-apps-with-vbnet/